# Automatically updating a file with Revision from TFS?

Tags: .net, tfs, msbuild

I'm quite new to TFS (actually I only use it because I have some projects on CodePlex and did not want to go through svnbridge), and I'm looking for something equivalent to the $Revision$ parameter in SVN.

Essentially on checkout, I want to update a file to contain the newest Revision number, to be displayed as Version number (just like at the bottom of SO).

Is there anything already built-in in msbuild of .net 3.5 SP1, or any official/standard msbuild task, or even something equivalent of just dropping $Revision$ and having the TFS client do the magic on checkout?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keyword expansion is not currently supported in TFS. This often takes people by suprise. Below are a couple of blog posts on the topic, you will also find a link there to take you to the Microsoft site if you want to vote for the feature.  I know that it is something that the Team get asked for from time to time - but they have yet to come across anyone that actually *needs* keyword expansion anymore, just a lot of folks are kinda just used to it.

Anyway - have a read and see what you think.

- [Buck Hodges - Keyword expansion in TFS](http://blogs.msdn.com/buckh/archive/2007/07/07/keyword-expansion-in-tfs.aspx)
- [Me - Why have Keyword Expansion?](http://www.woodwardweb.com/programming/why_have_keywor.html)

Comment: Thanks. Well, I agree on the questionable usage scenario of many keywords, but Revision (or any other way to get the Changeset Number) is one that is really useful when doing regular builds.

Comment: @Martin is the link for the feature vote still around? Couldn't find anything about keyword expansion for TFS. I agree there are very few valid use cases however I am currently sitting on a problem where it seems like one of the better ways to solve it. Lots of questions around SSRS and understanding the version of the deployed report but thats a different topic :)

Answer (score 3):

Michael,

From within a Team Build you can access the changeset number being built using the $(SourceGetVersion) variable. You could override the AfterGet or BeforeCompile extensibility targets and push the contents of this variable into whatever files you need it in.

Regards,

William D. Bartholomew (Team System MVP)