# Inserting version number to source code

Tags: visual-studio-2008

We are using Team foundation server 2012 with VS2008.
Is there any way to insert Version(Changeset) number into source file while checking In? We have some developers working on files outside TFS. So it is helpful if we able to insert version number into source code.Any way?pls help

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automatically updating a file with Revision from TFS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/841625/automatically-updating-a-file-with-revision-from-tfs)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need some keyword substitution. There already exists a check-in policy provided on Codeplex http://logsubstpol.codeplex.com/  which also has a VS2008 version, but not sure how it interacts with TFS2012.

Another option would be to create you own eventsubscriber (http://blog.hinshelwood.com/team-foundation-server-2010-event-handling-with-subscribers/), which runs on the Application Tier and should be therefor client independent. Did the same with TFS2012, except the path which changed to 11.0 instead of 2010 and of course the versions of the API references.

Comment: Thanks for reply, we already tried that one. It works fine but they have current version of a file=previous changeset number+1,which is not true for all files if we do not check in all file at once.

Comment: It should only set the changeset number in files you check in, other files should be ignored. The reason why they use "previous changeset number+1" is, that this is done before checking in, so there is no changeset number. Otherwise you need to do a tool/service that will do the substitution after check in was done.

Comment: The fault is it takes previous changeset of particular file and adds 1,but not latest changeset number in whole team project,and that is wrong sometimes.It would be useful if there is a tool/service that will do the substitution after check in was done.

Comment: Ok, I thought it would use the latest changeset number of TFS, not of each specific file. If you want to do this after checkin, you would have a recursion, because changing after checking in requires a new check in, which will trigger your substitution again ;) You could take the policy from Codeplex and customize it to use the latest changeset of TFS instead.

Comment: ya..recursion will be a problem..I will see what i can do.. thank you

Comment: hey,have you tried customizing codeplex policy? I am not getting idea what to do

Comment: No, haven't done it, but I would suggest that this method: `public LogSubstPolSetting Load(TeamProject args, LogSubstPolSetting cachedSetting)`  in `LogSubstPol.cs` is the key, especially this line `var i = args.VersionControlServer.GetItem(item, VersionSpec.Latest);`. If you replace the item with the root, you should get the actual changeset of TFS.

Comment: can i change in downloaded file? i cant find .cs file in downloaded content

Comment: you need to download the sources http://logsubstpol.codeplex.com/SourceControl/BrowseLatest, change this and recompile it. So it requires some developer knowledge and Visual Studio to do this.

Comment: I edited my post for another option, maybe that will fit your needs better, but it also needs some implementation effort.

Comment: I edited item to '$/'and compiled and placed .dll file to original folder.then i ran install.cmd..dll file copied to %USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\LogSubstPol. after restarting VS2008 its still behaving in old way.Is there anything i am missing?

Comment: They are getting previous version by 'pendingchanges.version'I don't know how to change that. see formatArgs method.